# Use Kmodes in Python with a big csv file

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, unsupervised-learning

I would like some assist with a problem I have. I have a big csv file (6239292, 5) and want to perform an unsupervised machine learning technique (kmodes). My code is this:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
print("initialising")


syms = np.genfromtxt('foo.csv', delimiter = ';', dtype=str, skip_header=1, invalid_raise=False)[:, 0:]

print(syms.shape)

X = np.genfromtxt('foo.csv',dtype=object, delimiter=';', invalid_raise=False, skip_header=1)[:, 1:]

X[1:, 0] = X[1:, 0].astype(float) 

from kmodes.kprototypes import KPrototypes

print("Imported successfully")
kproto = KPrototypes(n_clusters=6, init='random', n_init=2, verbose=2)
clusters = kproto.fit_predict(X, categorical=[2,1,3,])
```

Due to the size of the file, it's taking forever. Is there any technique I could use to reduce the time? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can select the first n rows like:

```
read_csv(..., nrows=999999)
```

or skip some rows and then select the next n rows:

```
read_csv(..., skiprows=1000000, nrows=999999)
```

There shouldn't be a problem with your results due to the [Central Limit Theorem](https://towardsdatascience.com/understanding-the-central-limit-theorem-642473c63ad8)

> The Central Limit Theorem (CLT) is a statistical theory states that
>   given a sufficiently large sample size from a population with a finite
>   level of variance, the mean of all samples from the same population
>   will be approximately equal to the mean of the population.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Never thought of approaching the problem from a more statistical point of view - was always looking for the IT solution.

Comment: I'm glad you like it, let me know if it works as expected